# Calling server side event handler in asp.net from client side java script

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a count down timer in javascript. Once the timer is 0 seconds, I want the page to run the code in button1_click event handler.

Scenario: I am doing a quiz engine.  When the time finishes, the quiz responses has to be submitted for which I want to run the button1_click event handler.

Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, albeit not necessarily the most correct, way is to simply use ASP.NET's JS function for submitting the web form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function timerRunOut() {
        __doPostBack('id_of_button','');
    }
</script>
```

You can get the ID of the button by doing:

```
__doPostBack('<%= myButton.ClientID %>', '');
```

For more details, here's a good article on [Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.2).

Comment: I tried doing a postback but it just re loads the page. I want the event handler to be triggered. Any idea how?  Thanks.

Comment: @unknown if you target the ID of the button which has the OnClick event handler assigned, it will invoke that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("<%= myButton.ClientID %>").onclick();
```

Comment: When I use the above method , I get a script error saying object is not supported... If this could work, it would be so easy... Where I am wrong? Thanks..